# I cant create metaboxes for custom post in wordpress..what's wrong in this code?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the code i wrote to create metabox..I am new to wordpress just begin to learn....
After creating  custom post types and metabox it shows only custom post type..not the metabox what's wrong in this code??..Please help me. I am on wordpress 3.9

```
add_action( 'init', 'cwd_movie_database' );
add_action('add_meta_boxes','cwd_movie_metabox');


function cwd_movie_database() {
$labels = array(
    'name'               => 'Movies',
    'singular_name'      => 'Movie',
    'menu_name'          => 'Movies',
    'name_admin_bar'     => 'Movie',
    'add_new'            => 'Add New Movie',
    'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Movie',
    'new_item'           => 'New Movie',
    'edit_item'          => 'Edit Movie',
    'view_item'          => 'View Movie',
    'all_items'          => 'All Movies',
    'search_items'       => 'Search Movies',
    'parent_item_colon'  =>  'Parent Movies:',
    'not_found'          => 'No Moviess found.',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Movies found in Trash.',
);

$args = array(
    'labels'             => $labels,
    'public'             => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui'            => true,
    'show_in_menu'       => true,
    'query_var'          => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'movie' ),
    'capability_type'    => 'post',
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'hierarchical'       => false,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments','categories','custom-fields' )
);

register_post_type( 'cwd_movies', $args );
}


function cwd_movie_metabox()
{
  add_meta_box('cwd_movie','Movie Details','cwd_movie_meta','cwd_movies','movies','side','default');
}

function cwd_movie_meta()
{
   echo 'Working';
}

?>
```

Comment: WordPress-Version? Try to add `add_action('add_meta_boxes','cwd_movie_metabox');` into the `init` process (and after your custom_post_type-Setup)!

Comment: wordpress version 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the meta-box after initalisation, best: after your custom-post-type-setup:

```
add_action( 'init', 'cwd_movie_database' );
// REMOVE: add_action('add_meta_boxes','cwd_movie_metabox');

function cwd_movie_database() {
    /* ... */
    register_post_type( 'cwd_movies', $args );

    // ADD: 
    add_action('add_meta_boxes','cwd_movie_metabox');
}
```

Be sure that you set the correct parameters. Here is a example from my site:

```
function add_meta_boxes($post_type) {
    add_meta_box(
        'news_visibility', 
        __('Visibility', ZVA_I18N), 
        array($this, 'render_meta_box_content'), 
        $post_type, 
        'advanced', 
        'high'
    );
}
```